# Проверка на pixel perfect

Tags: вёрстка

Некоторые заказчики пишут желаемый процент pixel perfect вёрстки по макету, например, не менее 90%. Как определяется этот процент? Есть какая-то фича, или это делается на глаз?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не менее 90% = нет серьезных отхождений от макета. Сетка не поехала, размеры не потеряны. Очень условная метрика.

Инструментов, которые тестируют pixel perfect и выдают результат в процентах, не встречал. Но для проверки PP путем наложения фотографии на страницу сайта юзаю:

- [PixelParallel by htmlBurger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pixelparallel-by-htmlburg/iffnoibnepbcloaaagchjonfplimpkob)

или

- [PerfectPixel by WellDoneCode (pixel perfect)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/perfectpixel-by-welldonec/dkaagdgjmgdmbnecmcefdhjekcoceebi)

Функционал почти одинаковый, выбирайте на вкус и цвет.